# Keep queryset annotations after combining tow querysets

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm currently struggling with the behavior of django querysets with annotations and the included operators | and &

I have Models like this:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    obj = PropertyManager()

class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    values = models.ManyToManyField(Property)

class PropertyManager(models.Manager):
    def included(self, profile):
        super(PropertyManager, self).filter(Q(property__profile=profile)).annotate(included_value=Value('true', output_field=CharField()))

    def excluded(self, profile):
        super(PropertyManager, self).filter(~Q(property__profile=profile)).annotate(included_value=Value('false', output_field=CharField()))

    def included_excluded(self, profile):
        return (self.excluded(profile) | self.included(profile)).distinct()
```

I naively expected that the `included_excluded` function returns a joined queryset of both querysets with their annotations, like:

```
property_id | included_value
------------|---------------
          1 |   true
          2 |   false
```

but it turns out, that the annotation is overwritten in my examples:

```
j = Profile.objects.get(id=1)
exc = Property.obj.excluded(profile=j)
inc = Property.obj.included(profile=j)
all = Property.obj.included_excluded(profile=j)

len(inc)  => 14
len(exc)  => 17
len(all)  => 31

all.values_list("included_value")  => <QuerySet [('false',)]>
exc.values_list("included_value")  => <QuerySet [('false',)]>
inc.values_list("included_value")  => <QuerySet [('true',)]>
```

`all` has obviously not all the correct values in the annotations, as I expected.

So I'm wondering, if there is a method to join two querysets and keep the annotations I made earlier

Answer (score 1):

From Django 1.8 upwards you can do it like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Case, When

def included_excluded(self, profile):
    return super(PropertyManager, self).annotate(
        included_value=Case(
            When(property__profile=profile, then='true'),
            default='false', output_field=models.CharField()
        )
    )
```

If you need them separately, then you can later just filter this queryset: `PropertyManager().included_excluded(profile).filter(included_value='true')`.